# Doesn't allow php file to open manually from url

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I want to disable opening of `.php` file manually from url in Apache and Nginx server.

For example

I have file in one folder like: `folder/abc.php`

Then if i open directly this file from url like: `www.example.com/folder/abc.php` then it should not be open and it should be redirect to some restriction pages like this.

I want this should be done in both cases: Apache and Nginx.

Comment: You can use htaccess. And set rules according your requirements.

Comment: can you give me rules for .htaccess and what about nginx bcoz htaccess will not work there

Comment: Share your htaccess code first.

Comment: i dont have any so i have asked here..my file is directly opening now so

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is to include something like this at top of your file

```
if ( $REQUEST_URL == $URL_OF_CURRENT_PAGE ) 
{
//Redirect to some url
}
```

Here is a example
suppose your url is http://www.example.com/folder/abc.php

```
//Get current url
$REQUEST_URL="http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

if($REQUEST_URL=="http://www.example.com/folder/abc.php"){
    //Redirect to some url
}
```

Comment: so it means that if my domain is example.com then i cant upload any files from other domains like example1.com

Comment: check i gave an example

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by making a .htaccess file in the root dir of the webserver:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`

Answer (score 0):

You can forbid access to specific folder files in nginx configuration like this.(Exclude public folder). Use regular expression.

```
location ~* ^\/folder1\/(?!public\/).*$ {
    deny all;
}
```